# Protractor: Unable to run specific TC assigned with FIT in Protractor

Tags: automation, protractor

After create TC using it and class using describe.
I am trying to run specific tc using fit, but whole suite is getting executed in protractor.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Are you running tests in parallel? `fit` doesn't work for me when I do that. Only when I run them serially. Disable the parallel runs and it should work.

Comment: @tehbeardedone: I am running code serially. fit doen't work

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jasmine before version 2.1, fit doesn't work. You'll have to use iit to run a single it and ddescribe to run a single describe. This has changed to fit and fdescribe for versions after 2.1. Try this, it might work or update your jasmine to the latest version.